# Programmatically open NSWindow in another Desktop (Space)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, macos, cocoa

In my OSX Project I want to:

- identify the Desktop (one of the expose Spaces) where a NSWindow resides;
- open a NSWindow in a determined Space, not only on current Space.

Is there a way to do these simple tasks?

Exploring the documentation (NSWindowController, NSWindow, NSScreen) I can't find anything regarding multiple Desktop Management.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd think there would be some API for working with Spaces, but there really isn't. You can use **CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo** to determine which Space a particular window is on, but there's no easy way to open a particular window on a specific space.

There is *private* API to move windows between spaces, of course. Whether you want to use this in your application depends on your needs - you couldn't use it on a Mac App Store application, obviously.

Found a copy-of-a-copy of the reverse-engineered header I was looking for:
https://gist.github.com/rjw57/5495406

Comment: Thank you Mark. I contact Apple DTS and they told me: Our engineers have reviewed your request and have concluded that there is no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the currently shipping system configurations. :(

Comment: Yeah, they really need to step up on documenting/supporting CoreGraphicsServices. I will definitely be telling them that at the next WWDC.