# os x: screen has several spaces, can I set window in specific space?

Tags: objective-c, macos, screen, screenshot

I am developing a screen capture app, when the screen has several spaces, I want to set my window in a specific space, but really, I googled a lot, but did not find any useful. 
So please, hope someone can give me a hint, thanks very much.

Comment: I suggest you run a search for spaces here.

Comment: @ElTomato thanks very much. I finally found answer in another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461347/programmatically-open-nswindow-in-another-desktop-space